# Negative small numbers in Clojure

Tags: clojure

During my clojure studies, I found this:

```
;Clojure 1.4.0
(def neg_inf -1E-400)
(cond
    (= neg_inf 0) "Zero"
    (< neg_inf 0) "Negative"
    (> neg_inf 0) "Positive"
    :default "Neither"
)
;#'user/neg_inf
;user=> "Neither"
```

Is it a bug?

Then, I tried:

```
(Math/signum -1E-400) ;-0.0
```

Here's a way I found to discover when some number is considered as -0.0 :

```
(Math/copySign 1. -0.) ;-1.0
(Math/copySign 1. -1E-99999999999999999999999);-1.0
```

This way, I can know if a number is negative even if it is ridiculously close to zero.

All of this because I were trying to solve this problem:

```
(defn hexadecimal-to-degrees [rah ram ras]
     { :pre [ (>= rah 0) (< rah 24) (>= ram 0) (< ram 60) (>= ras 0) (< ras 60) ]
       :post [ (>= % 0) ]
     }
     (/ (+ rah (/ ram 60) (/ ras 3600)) 15)
)

(hexadecimal-to-degrees -1E-400 -1E-400 -1E-400)
;-0.0 ; OMG, no Assert failed here!
```

Since there is no negative value for Right Ascension (the celestial equivalent of terrestrial longitude), I was testing if the post condition works in a way that
guarantees the function will not return a negative value for the RA no matter what
numbers I pass to the function..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect that the `(= 0 -1E-400)` uses java's `Double.equals()` method under the hood, which treats the positive and negative zeros as unequal. This behavior is a violation of the IEEE floating point standard. The other comparison operators translate to other methods which behave according to the standard, i.e. treat +0.0 and -0.0 as equal.

To get the standard-compliant behavior, use the number-equivalence operator `==`.  Thus, `(== 0 -0.0)` evaluates to `true`.

More about signed and unsigned zero on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero

On a more general note: comparing floating point numbers for equality should always raise suspicions.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right.  
Please, look at this:  
    `scala> -1E-400 < 0`  
    `res13: Boolean = false`

Comment: @user1680095: The interesting operator would be equality. Does Scala consider -1e-400 equal to zero?

Comment: Yes,  `scala> -1E-400 == 0`  
      `res15: Boolean = true`  It seems then Scala don't suffer the same problem as Clojure (Java):  `public static void main(String[] args) { System.out.println(Double.valueOf(-0D).equals(0D)); } //false`

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that the behavior of Doubles implies a performance compromise between processor time and accuracy. Clojure makes it easy to work with BigDecimals, which are computationally more expensive but have better accuracy guarantees. You can specify BigDecimal numeric literals by appending 'M' after the literal number, and all numeric operators accept BigDecimals. Quick test drive relevant to your example:

```
user> (type -1E-400)
java.lang.Double
user> (type -1E-400M)
java.lang.BigDecimal

user> (= 0M -1E-400M)
false
user> (<= 0M -1E-400M)
false
user> (< 0M -1E-400M)
false
user> (>= 0M -1E-400M)
true
```

Comment: That will work.  But I was concerned with integers at least for the
ra and de parameters in my function, so I could use the 'N' postfix
instead.  On the other hand, performance if of my concern because such function is intended to be used very frequently.